# What is the relation between $\eta^{ab}x^2$ and $x^ax^b$?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

What is the relation between $\eta^{ab}x^2$ and $x^ax^b$? Here $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric in $d=4$ and $x$ is a 4-vector.

In particular, a tensor like $$x^a x^b x^c (\eta_{ab}x^2 - x_ax_b) \tag{1} $$
is zero, thus the contractions are identical. So, is there a mistake or so?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: Such a thing, but instead of 4-vectors having 4-momenta appear in Feynman diagrams.

Comment: I do not understand what that comment is trying to say.

Comment: Terms like (1) show up in Feynman diagrams loop corrections. Not sure how I can answer better on this.

Comment: The two tensors are certainly not equal. its fairly easy to see that if you let x be a null vector. Then $\eta^{00}x^{2}$=0 but $x^{0}x^{0}\neq0$.
You're point of confusion is that when calculating Lorentz invariant integrals, like those that appear in Feynman diagrams, we can replace $x^{a}x^{b}$ with $\eta^{ab}x^{2}$ in the integrand. That does not mean they are equal only that they yield identical terms after computing the integral.

Comment: @Marion: Your second comment makes sense, your first comment does not. (at least to me, perhaps someone else would have been able to understand what you meant).

Comment: A tensor like $x^{a}x^{b}\eta^{ab}$ is not a valid tensor.  Do you mean $x_{a}x_{b}\eta^{ab}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo.

Comment: @DavidMeltzer When you use them in Feynman diagrams, one must also divide by the dimension in the integrand, that is, you change $\ell^\mu \ell^\nu \to \frac{1}{d}\eta^{\mu\nu}\ell^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand your terms, it goes like $$ x^ax^bx^c\eta_{ab}x^2-x^ax^bx^cx_ax_b, $$ but since $$x^2=x^ax_a=x^ax^b\eta_{ab} $$ it is $$ x^4x^c-x^4x^c, $$ and that is zero.
But, $ \eta_{ab}x^2 $ is not equal to $ x_ax_b $, just think that two tensors are equal if in a given basis their components are equal, and $\eta_{ab}x^2$ in matrix form has components only in the diagonal, while generally this isn't true for (and upon first look I think it cannot be true) for $x_ax_b$.

Edit:
Also, since you asked about relations, let us use mixed variances, and think of our tensors as operators. Then $$ x^2\delta^a_b $$ is an operator that multiplies a vector by $x^2$, while $$ x^ax_b $$is an operator that takes a vector's scalar product with $\mathbf{x}$ and then multiplies it with $\mathbf{x}$. If $\mathbf{x}$ is a unit vector, then this is a projection to the subspace spanned by $\mathbf{x}$.
If you use these operators on $\mathbf{x}$ itself, then they will give the same result, since $$ x^2\delta^a_bx^b=x^2x^a $$ and $$ x^ax_bx^b=x^2x^a. $$